# Regex check for non-match

Tags: regex, aws-amplify

anyone know proper regex syntax to say everything **except** `/examplepath` ? I've tried `</^((?!examplepath).)*$/>`  , `</^((?!\/examplepath\/).)*$/>` with no luck

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure, its used by Amplify for redirects / rewrites

Comment: Ah, that's where the weird delimiters come from :-) Hm, these should work, although they don't match anything except `/examplepath`, but anything that doesn't *contain* `/examplepath` (anywhere in the string)

Comment: I'd suggest `/</^(?!examplepath)/>` maybe?

Comment: thanks for the help, I've tried that with no luck

Comment: Perhaps like this `</^(?!\/examplepath$).*$/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

> "^(?!str1$|str2$).{min_number,max_number_of_chars}$"

and validate it here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yes I was going to say https://regex101.com/ a very good site for playing with regex